# How to access the DCIM folder on Android 8.1

Tags: android

I'm trying to save a file in the folder `DCIM` on my mobile phone (Samsung SM-N960F, Android 8.1.0); I'm using

```
Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM)
```

to create a folder in the folder `DCIM`, but it's not working.

Comment: Can you share your code? It's easier to understand your problem if we can see the code you're using, and any specific error messages you're receiving.

Comment: I believe all questions need to be in english for stackoverflow. Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: I'm trying to save a file in the folder "DCIM" on my mobile phone (Samsung SM-N960F, Android 8.1.0); I'm using Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM) to create a folder in the folder 'DCIM', but it's not working.

Comment: @Steven you're right. I proposed an edit with translation, but [that's not the right answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/297673/how-do-i-deal-with-non-english-content). The author needs to post in English; this helps assure they'll be able to make use of the English answers they'll receive.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you do not have the proper permission for reading and writing to external storage. Add this to your project's build.manifest,

```
<manifest>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    ...
</manifest>
```

Comment: merci pour votre reponse, j'ai bien ajouté les permissions et j'arrive à creer des dossier sur d'autre mobiles (android 4.1, 5.1) mais pas sur un android 8.1